# Campaign trigger

Tags: trigger, campaign

Can someone help me to create a trigger on Campaigns that adds the number of Leads added to a certain campaign so that I can override the Total Leads field with the correct value.

Thanks,
Darko

Comment: I don't understand the difference between what you are looking to calculate and the standard behavior of the Total Leads field. You can't write to the Total Leads field in any case - you'd need to create a new custom field to hold the result you're trying to calculate. Finally, noone here is going to write your code for you; you have to show some effort and then people can answer specific questions you may have.

Comment: Hi Thomas,
I am newbie with triggers and that is why i've asked.
Here is what i've found that might be out of a help to me.
It basically adds the new leads to the campaign that has equal value with the lead source. This code i found it on the net but i am not sure if it satisfying my needs.http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2008/09/13/bulkifying-a-trigger-an-example/
 Because I got a DB with more than 30k leads that are already on SF and i want them to be assigned to the correct campaign..
Please advise,
Darko

Comment: Do you want to assign your 30k existing Leads to Campaigns, auto-assign any new Leads to Campaigns, or both? Triggers are not the way to get existing Leads assigned to a Campaign - for that you should use regular Campaign population tools like Searching for Leads from the Campaign, or building a Report and using the Add to Campaign button. For future leads, that trigger can be useful. Is Lead Source the field you want to use to select the Campaign?

Comment: Thomas you are the man. With the report and adding to campaign you made my day!!! 
For the trigger i will implement it in future because it will do the job for me automatically.
Thanks,
Darko